# Many-to-many relationship with additional foreign key

Tags: database, laravel, database-design, eloquent, lumen

I'm building a simple cookbook API using [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/).

At this point, the setup is this:

- a **many-to-many** relationship:

  - `recipe` has many `ingredient`s
  - `ingredient` has many `recipe`s
- a **one-to-many** relationship:

  - `recipe` has many `step`s

The **many-to-many** relationship is implemented using an associative table, `ingredient_recipe`:

[image: db-1]

This works as expected and allows me to access, for example, `$someRecipe->ingredients` to get all ingredients linked to a specific recipe.

However — and this is the part that I'm not really sure about — given a specific `recipe-ingredient` relationship, an `ingredient` also has a specific `measure` (e.g. 'milliliter') and amount.

The way I'm solving this at this time is by simply adding a `measure_id` to each `recipe-ingredient` relationship in the associative table:

[image: db-2]

I accomplish this with the following code:

```
$recipe->ingredients()->attach($ingredient_model, ['amount' => GIVEN_AMOUNT, 'measure_id' => GIVEN_MEASURE_ID);
```

This works, but makes the query to get the amount and measure for each ingredient in a given recipe slightly more complicated.

My question: is there another, maybe more `Eloquent` way to accomplish this that I'm not seeing? Or are there other database design best practices for these types of cases that  I'm not aware of?

Comment: From the database point of view, this is the correct solution.

Comment: this is correct.  one extension would be to have another column on ingredient that tells you the amount of each ingredient available (of that measure)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my situation is: there are orders and products for each, many to many, each product has its own unit of measure and quantity for each order, something like this:
[pre-model of database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzxQY.png)

I don't know if this is correct but I just added a method to the product model

```
public function measurement()
{
    $measurement = Measurement::find($this->pivot->measurement_id);

    return $measurement;
}
```

and now I can use that

```
@foreach ($order->products as $product)
    {{ $product->measurement()->name }}
@endforeach
```

I think you just need to add to ingredient model

```
public function measure()
{
    $measure = Measure::find($this->pivot->measure_id);

    return $measure;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Recipe Model
public function recipes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Recipe')->withTimestamps();
    }
// Ingredient Model
 public function ingredients()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Ingredient ')->withTimestamps();
    }

// Controller 
public function index()
    {
        $recipes= Recipe ::latest()->get();
        return view('admin.recipes.index',compact('recipes'));
    }

// Blade file

 @foreach($recipesas $key=>$recipe)
<tr>
<td>{{$recipe->ingredients->name}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```